# Is it possible to pass multiple input values in stored procedure parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a fantasy baseball optimizer and I have a stored procedure where when the user selects players it will return the best possible player, but the problem is, the sp only does it for one player at a time. I wanted to know if there was a way the sp could do it for at most nine players at one time.
[Visual Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRlTb.png)

Here's the code for the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`u998875936_chri`@`%` PROCEDURE `Optimizer9`(
PlayerName varchar(30), 
PlayerPosition varchar(2),
PlayerSalary int,
PlayerFPPG Numeric (20,17),
CapRemaining int,
OUT ReturnPlayerName varchar(30),
OUT ReturnCap int
)
BEGIN

Declare Count int;
Declare lclSal int;
Declare lclPlayerName varchar(30);
Declare lclReturnPlayerName varchar(30);
Declare lclCap int;

Set lclPlayerName='';
Set lclReturnPlayerName='';
Set lclSal=0;
Set lclCap = CapRemaining;
Set Count=0;



create temporary Table IF NOT EXISTS TempPlayer9(
Player varchar(30),
Pos varchar(2),
Sal int,
Points Numeric (20,17)
);


Insert into TempPlayer9 (Player,Pos,Sal,Points)

    SELECT Nickname
      ,Position
      ,Salary
      ,FPPG
  FROM playerList
  WHERE POSITION = PlayerPosition
   and FPPG > PlayerFPPG
       order by FPPG DESC; 

Set Count=(Select Count(*) from TempPlayer9);

While Count > 0
     DO
       Set lclPlayerName=(Select Player from TempPlayer9 LIMIT 1);
       Set lclSal=(Select Sal from TempPlayer9 LIMIT 1);
       IF (lclsal- PlayerSalary) < lclCap
      THEN         
            Set lclCap = lclCap - (lclSal- PlayerSalary);
            Set lclReturnPlayerName = lclPlayerName;
            Set Count=0;

        DELETE from TempPlayer9 Where Player = lclPlayerName;
        Set Count=Count-1       ;
        END IF;
        END WHILE;
Set ReturnPlayerName = lclReturnPlayerName;  
Set ReturnCap = lclCap;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 

$remain=35000; 
$player= $_POST['player'];
$pos= $_POST['pos'];
$sal= $_POST['sal'];
$points= $_POST['fppg'];
$cap= $remain-$sal; 


$sql = $mysqli->query("call Optimizer11('$player', '$pos','$sal' , '$points', '$cap', @ReturnPlayerName, @ReturnCap)");
$results = $mysqli->query ("select @ReturnPlayerName as Player,@ReturnCap AS SalRemaining");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results);

print_r($rows);

?>
```

Comment: Why is all of this happening in a stored procedure instead of in application code where it's a lot easier to work with? Why is the name `TempPlayer9`? Are there 8 other tables doing other mysterious things?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code. You're making two object-oriented calls, and then a procedural one after for no reason.